# exec sh from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to run a .sh file loading from a .py file in a PySpark's job but I receive a message always saying that .sh file is not found

This is my code:

test.py:

```
import os,sys
os.system("sh ./check.sh")
```

and my gcloud command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster mserver file:///home/myuser/test.py
```

test.py file is loaded well but the system can't find check.sh file
I figure out that is something related with the file's path but not sure

I tried also with `os.system("sh home/myuser/check.sh")` and same result

I think that this should be easy to do so ... ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The "current working directory" used by Dataproc jobs submitted through the API is a temporary directory with a unique name for each job; if the file wasn't uploaded with the job itself, you'll have to access it using your absolute path.

If you indeed added the `check.sh` file manually to `/home/myuser/check.sh`, then you should be able to call it using the fully qualified path, `os.system("sh /home/myuser/check.sh")`; make sure to start your absolute path with a `/`.